# Problem with OAuth2 google (Missing authorization code)

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

This is one of my functions:

```php
public function handleGoogleCallback(){
    $parameters = ['access_type' => 'offline'];

    $driver = Socialite::driver('google')->with($parameters);
    $user = $driver->stateless()->user();
    // dd($user);
    // $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile(public_path('google_ads_php.ini'))->build();
    $accessToken = $user->token;
    $authorizationCode = $_GET['code'];

    // $this->afterGoogleCallback($user,$authorizationCode,$accessToken);
    $clientid = config('values.Client_ID');
    $clientSecret = config('values.Client_secret');
    $developerToken = config('values.developer_token');
    $redirect_uri = config('values.redirect_uri');
    $array = [
        'authorizationCode' => $authorizationCode,
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'access_token' => $accessToken,
        'tokenCredentialUri' => 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
        'clientId' => $clientid,
        'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
        'redirectUri' => $redirect_uri,
        'developerToken' => $developerToken,
        'refreshToken' => null, // If you have a refresh token, add it here
    ];

    try {
        $oauth2Credentials = new OAuth2($array);
        $googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
            ->fromFile(public_path('google_ads_php.ini'))
            ->withOAuth2Credential($oauth2Credentials)
            ->build();
    
        $this->runExample($googleAdsClient,$authorizationCode);
```

and the second gives me the error:

```php
public static function runExample(GoogleAdsClient $googleAdsClient,$authorizationCode){
   // dd($authorizationCode);
   
   $customerServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getCustomerServiceClient();
   dd($customerServiceClient);
   
   // Create an array of optional arguments
   $optionalArgs = [];
   
   // Issues a request for listing all accessible customers.
   $accessibleCustomers = $customerServiceClient->listAccessibleCustomers(); (on this line)
```

I am trying to retrieve Google Ads accounts and IDs from the logged-in user but I am having problems.